# Mathematical logic: is a system in a first-order language maximal?

Tags: logic

In some lecture notes I'm reading the following question is asked as an exercise:

Is Sp (= a system in a first-order language) maximal?

Maximality is defined as follows: A theory T is maximal iff, for every formula A of the language, either A ∈ T or ~A ∈ T.

The solution which is given in the notes is the following:

No. For example, neither Pa nor ~Pa is provable in Sp.

I don't quite understand the solution; could you provide some help?

Many thanks.

Fish

Comment: What is "a system in a first-order language" ?

Comment: Here "system" means a formal language (in this case a first order language) + a deductive apparatus (consisting of a set of axioms and a set of inference rules - sometimes you can have, of course, inference rules only, as in natural deduction).

Comment: Is "Sp" a particular deductive system, then? We'd need to know more about it to say anything about the question. And what is "Pa"?

Comment: If $Sp$ is a *calculus* for FOL, like e.g. Natural Deduction, it is *sound*, i.e. it proves only *valid* formulas and neither $Pa$ nor $\lnot Pa$ are *valid*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mauro, I think that is the answer to my question!

Comment: The standard terminology for what  your lecture notes call "maximal" is "complete".  We can't help you with the question "is system Sp complete?" unless you tell us what system Sp is.

Comment: Sp is a system for a predicate language (with no additional axioms, not even identity).

Comment: I think Mauro got it right.